# Is there away to save selected filter for woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have Ecommerce store and would like to know if there is any known way to save selected filter when moving between pages? For instance choose and filter "blue" and then moving between shirts/pants/jackets back and forth while selected filter is saved until cleared. I've checked with team support of most plugins in the market and they all answered that their product cannot deliver the request. Any advice guys ?